# firestore security rule request.auth.uid is not working

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

Firestore security rules do not work.
Help me.
Document data of users/userid could not be read.

----------Security Rule------------

```
service cloud.firestore {
 match /databases/{database}/documents {
  match /users/{userId=**} {

  // Missing or insufficient permissions.
    allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId

  // this is work.
  //allow read, write: if request.auth != null

}
```

}
}

--------------main.js--------------------

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Quasar from 'quasar'
import firebase from 'firebase'
import 'firebase/firestore'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.use(Quasar)


let app;
firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  databaseURL: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: ""
})


firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user=> {
  if (user) {
    let ref = firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(user.uid)
    ref.get().then(snapshot=>{
      // Error !! : Missing or insufficient permissions.
    }
  }
  if(!app){
    Quasar.start(() => {
      app = new Vue({
        el: '#q-app',
        render: h => h(require('./App').default)
      })
    })
  }

})
```

firebase ^4.8.0
vue ^2.5.0

Apparently, require.auth.uid does not seem to work properly.
Where is there a mistake in me?

Comment: did you saved the auth.uid key as users key?

Comment: @ShinyaUeda - `request.auth != null` is not working for me. I'm having this issue for Android using `com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.0` despite being logged in on the app and seeing the User UID in the Firebase Auth console.

Comment: @Hareesh, any suggestions for debugging if `request.auth != null` is not working?

Comment: ```request.auth.uid != null``` is right out of the "Mixed public and private access" (and other parts) of the documentation at https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/insecure-rules#common_scenarios_with_insecure_rules

Answer (score 11):

---

I was able to solve it self

```
 match /users/{user} {
   allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == user
   match / {docs = **} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == user
   }
 }
```

---

Answer (score 8):

I followed the example I found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/start#sample-rules) (under the **User** tab) and it's working great:

```
// Grants a user access to a node matching their user ID
service firebase.storage {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId}/{documents=**} {
      allow read, write: if isOwner(userId);
    }
  }

  function isOwner(userId) {
    return request.auth.uid == userId;
  }
}
```

Comment: Works really good, just needed to change firebase.storage to cloud.firestore in my case. Thank you!

Comment: It worked for me. thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
 match /users/{userId}/{documents=**} {
  // return request.auth.uid == userId
  function isAuth(){
  return request.auth != null
  }
  allow read,write:if   (isAuth() && request.auth.uid == userId)    
}
```

this solution work for this error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).